# Is there any way to edit the kill-ring?

Tags: kill-ring

Are there any tools to directly edit the kill-ring?

If I open xah-show-kill-ring, I'm tempted to edit the contents directly.

Comment: So why not try it? What's the worst that can happen? In any case, did you `C-h v kill-ring`?

Comment: Why? What are you *really* trying to do? Sounds like an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821).

Comment: Well, right now I first copied the type of a variable, then I copied the name of the variable, which also included a comma at the end. Then I opened the kill buffer and wanted to move the type to the same entry as the name and remove the comma. It seemed like a natural thing to do. What I usually do is yank first what I have in the kill-ring, then open the kill-ring and yank the second part, then combine them and kill them again, so that I can yank it in to where I need it to be. I'm not really sure what is the best way, but I'd like to explore working directly on the kill-ring;)

Comment: Maybe a dumb idea, not sure, yet;)

Answer (score 4):

The [contents of the kill ring](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html) is, by definition, the value of the variable `kill-ring`, which is a list of strings. You can change the contents of the kill ring by modifying this variable and (depending on what you're doing) updating [`kill-ring-yank-pointer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Internals-of-Kill-Ring.html) accordingly.

I don't think Emacs comes with any convenient interface to edit the kill ring. You have to write Lisp code or use a third-party package.

At least [`browse-kill-ring`](https://github.com/browse-kill-ring/browse-kill-ring) (available from MELPA) and [`browse-kill-ring+`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/browse-kill-ring%2b.el) have an interface to edit and remove kill ring entries. (But not to add: just copy something. And not to reorder.)

There are many other [kill ring browsing interfaces](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing), but I don't know if they have editing capabilities.

Comment: No. [`browse-kill-ring+`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/browse-kill-ring%2b.el) is neither unmaintained nor a fork of anything. It enhances what `browse-kill-ring.el` offers. I've edited the answer to remove that characterization.